# @SqsListener(value = "${queue.name}") is unable to find the queue name

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to read messages from sqs using spring boot & java.
and i am keep getting an error the the queue name is not found in the region.
the queue is in the region and the work work ok localy

this is my code

```
@SqsListener(value = "${queue.name}", deletionPolicy =SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void receiveMessages(String msg) {
   logger.info("GOT THE MESSAGE: "+ msg);
}
```

Comment: What is the error message. Where you define `queue.name`?

Comment: What version of spring-cloud-aws are you using?

Comment: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.... and the queue.name in the name of my queue (not the url)

Comment: org.springframework.cloud version 2.0.1

Comment: Value extracted ok, i am seeing it in the log

Comment: are you sure that AWS keys are correctly configured? It doesn't seem to connect to AWS

Comment: the sqs and my app are in 2 different aws account, and trying to connect to my sqs with assumerule